# How to make Google Analytics Data public?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there currently any way to show Google Analytics data from my GA Account on my web site without any user authentication? I would like to show most popular pages, and perhaps most popular searches and so on. I am looking for a way to do this that wouldnt need me to build a proxy service over the API and be subject to quotas and limits and so on.

Comment: Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/). Built specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GA does not currently offer a way to access data without user authentication, even through the API.

Comment: What about a service account. One could simply create a service account collect the data and display it however they wish.

Comment: @Matt Firstly, this answer (and question) is old (little over 2 years!).  Google has since released [Google Analytics superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) which does exactly what OP wanted.  But to address your comment: at the time (and even now, with the regular GA API), creating a service account would work, if you want it to be public. However, you'd have to display the login creds on your web page for a visitor to authenticate through GA. IOW it was impossible to NOT involve the visitor before.  But now you can, with superProxy

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google Apps script](http://script.google.com) the output of which you can then embed into a page. They provide a GA connector and when publishing the web app, you can select to allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea like this:

1. Create a button, where you obtain a OAuth2 access token (on admin side probably)
2. Store token to somewhere(db, file, etc)
3. Make a cron job to renew token every hour (3600 seconds)

Comment: Wouldn't a service account work better than creating a web interface to authorize a chron job.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the responses to this question are out-dated.

Specifically, 
I was able to fetch the data from my server (I get an XML response),
I am still trying to figure out how to easily parse this XML into data which can be used by javascript to visualize.

I know that the ga easy dashboard library (gadash) does that very well, but that one relies on the queries being made form the library itself (with authentication), and that is exactly what we are trying to avoid.

Anyone has an idea on how to use the XML data we recieved to display the graphs?

I would be happy to show how I fetch the xml if we arrive at a full solution

Ilan

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics Demos & Tools is a resource for users and developers to discover what's possible with the Google Analytics Platform. Learn how to implement GA and applications that can be built to take advantage of the flexibility and power of Google Analytics.

The code for this entire site is open source and available on GitHub. We encourage you to take a look if you'd like to see how anything is done.

[Google Analytics Tools](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/)

[Google Analytics Demos & Tools on Github](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy Would also work